# using the jquery on method to know when a hash changes in the url

Tags: jquery

so I have a url which could be mywebsite.com/index.html#Jobs

I first need to get the name after the hash which I do by

```
var $ext = $(location).attr('hash');
$ext= $ext.replace("#","");
```

the problem is know when this hash tag has changed on a live event and not a page refresh

this is what i have tried

```
var $ext = $(location).attr('hash');

$ext.('change', function() {

  console.log("changed");
});
```

I know this doesnt work as $ext isnt an element but would like some help.

any ideas very welcome.

Comment: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use This Plugin : http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/

And Use This Code:

```
$(window).hashchange( function() {
    var hash = location.hash;
    myfunc(hash);
});
function myfunc(hash)  {
    alert(hash);
}
```

You can also use but some compatibility issues  :

```
window.onhashchange = function() {
    alert(window.location.hash);
}
```

And for checking whether browser supports hashchange:

```
if ("onhashchange" in window) {
    alert("The browser supports the hashchange event!");
}
```